# IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level while dividing

Tags: python, runtime-error, indentation, division

I'm just trying to get the division done with the following code:

```py
def division(a,b):
     return a/b 
    print(division (4,2))
```

And having the below Error.

```
D:\python>python -u "d:\python\learn1.py"
  File "d:\python\learn1.py", line 86
    print(division (4,2))
                         ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def division(a,b):
    return a/b 
print(division (4,2))
```

return will exists the function before reaching the print statement,on your code.So I had added print statement on outer indentation level.In python indentation plays a major role.

Comment: Could you explain why your answer solves the problem?

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, along with the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform, that differentiates it from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Python complains about indentation levels not matching. In order to make this work you should remove one space from the `print` line.

```py
def division(a,b):
    return a/b # removed one space here
    print(division (4,2))
```

But this is most likely not what you want, since your `print` line will never run because the `return` line exits the function before the `print` line ever runs.

So I'd guess what you want is the following:

```py
def division(a,b):
    return a/b
print(division(4,2))
```

This will first define your function `division` and then call it when resolving the arguments for `print`. The w3c page has a [tutorial for this](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_syntax.asp) which you might find interesting.